# how to run runSheduledTask.php file in cli

Tags: updates

when i am running runSheduledTasks.php from terminal, an error occured like "couldn't open input file:runSheduledTasks.php"
please give suggestion to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install php5-cli

2) Make sure your .php file start with

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

3) Make sure your file is executable.

```
chmod +x file.php
```

4) Now you should be abble to run this file for example with

```
./file.php
```

Comment: thanks, but still this is not working other files from /var/www folders are running in cli but these file is not opening and same error msg is display...